# 僕より先に どこか遠くに 旅立つことは 絶対 許さないから

Tags: meaning, parsing

So I have these lyrics ([source](http://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/aimer/kataomoi/)):

> ...君が僕を忘れてしまっても ちょっと辛いけど… それでもいいから

I completely understand that line, but this one is troubling me

> 僕より先に どこか遠くに 旅立つことは 絶対 許さないから

I thought maybe it would parse like this

> 僕より先にどこか - Somewhere before me
>
> 遠くに旅立つことは絶対許さないから - The fact that you go away from me is unforgivable

And everything would be:

> It's unforgivable that you go away from me, right before my eyes.

(I'm not sure if 先にどこか遠くに should be together or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse it this way:

> ｛僕より先に｝｛どこか遠くに｝旅立つことは｛絶対｝許さないから

僕より先に (before me; before I do) and どこか遠くに (somewhere far away) both modify 旅立つ.

「Vことは許さない」(を in 「Vことを許さない」 is replaced by は) means "don't allow (someone) to do~~"

Put together,

"I'll never allow you to leave for somewhere far away before I do."

... I think 遠くに旅立つ implies "pass away" here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the weird thing for me here, is that I'm used that the noun usually comes after what is modifying it, eg: 静かな部屋, so I thought that どこか遠くに could not be write because the noun comes before, Do you have another sentence as an example with that construction? Thanks in advance

Comment: @FelipeOliveira 遠く is the noun form of 遠い and means "a far away place" (≂ 遠い場所/遠いところ)". 「An interrogative + か」 is placed before a noun / noun phrase), eg  「 **何か食べ物を**ください。」「 **誰か好きな人は**いるの？」